# Xcode not showing @available warnings anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Xcode is not giving me warnings for properties or methods that are not available on all supported iOS version by the app anymore. This is a serious problem for me and could lead to bugs or app crashes on some iOS versions.

For example, the `[NSDate now]` method is only available on iOS 13 and above. Using this method on an iOS 12 device would lead to a crash. The current iOS Deployment Target of my app project is set to iOS 12.0 and the app is also supported for all versions above iOS 12. But for some reason I don't get a warning anymore if I use a method or property which is not available on iOS 12 and only on the version above.

I'm using Xcode 12.5. I also tried using Xcode 12.4 and the Xcode 13 Beta but it's the same. Is this a problem with the project?

Comment: On a new project, can you reproduce the issue? If no, check then `Build Settings`, there a are a few warning flags management there. Check if there is a diff between the working and non-working one. Or do you have somewhere `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`? Which might not have done the `pop`?

Comment: The "Apple Clang - Warnings - All languages" category in the Build Settings has the options "Unguarded availability" which did the thing. It was set to "No". After I set it to Yes and rebuilt the project I got the warning again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Build Settings`, you can search for `Unguarded availability` on the search bar, or  find it in `Apple Clang - Warnings - All Languages` section.

Set the value to `Yes`